# Using Contains or IndexOf with counter in C#

Tags: c#, replace

I'm trying to use a counter with Replace but no success.

```
int ObjN = 0;
while (editor.Rtf.Contains("CreateObject") == true) 
{
 editor.Rtf = editor.Rtf.Replace("CreateObject", "Object" + ObjN++);
}
```

Output is:

```
Object0
Object0
Object0
```

I expected

```
Object0
Object1
Object2
```

instead.  How can I get that output?

Comment: Even the title doesnt make sense with the code you've posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `"Object" + ObjN++` will be evaluated once before the `Replace` method is called, not for each replacement. Having the loop doesn't help, as the `Replace` method will replace all instances, not just the first.

If you use `Regex.Replace` you can specify a function to create the value:

```
int cnt = 0;
editor.Rtf = Regex.Replace(editor.Rtf, "CreateObject", m => "Object" + (cnt++));
```

Comment: Thanks. what does "m=>" mean? Match?

Comment: @Tom: It's a lambda expression, a short way of writing a function. The `m` would be the parameter in the function, which is the `Match` object that the `Replace` method calls the function with.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your replace statement will replace ALL instances of "CreateObject" in the string, it does not stop after replacing the first instance. Get rid of the replace line and instead search for the index of the first instance using .IndexOf and then replace it manually.